# Condensed Nearest Neighbor Algorithm - Confusion on Returning Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction

I have a question regarding the Condensed Nearest Neighbors algorithm: 
[image]

Why am I returning `Z`, which if I understand correctly, is the array of all of the misclassified points? Wouldn't I want to return the points that were classified correctly? What benefit does this give me in returning all the points I got wrong?

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts. CNN does not classify points, it just returns a subset of the original data such that you can run your KNN classifier with this smaller subset instead of the original full set and get similar results.

Comment: Yes...but it does so by testing the classification. See line 5 in the pseudocode posted.

Comment: Can you please explain the mark for closure comment? The question is rather explicit. Why are we returning the subset of points that we misclassified during the condensing technique, instead of the points that we classified correctly? How does using the misclassified subset result in the same accuracy later on during the testing set of KNN?

Comment: You are picking 2 instances that are very close to each other but have different class. That means it is highly possible that the new point is in a border that separates the classes, which means it is important to keep it in the set we will use later for classification. That´s why you add it to Z. If they were the same class, that means the new point gives no useful information than what we already have in Z, so we skip it and don´t add it. The intuition is that we try to only keep the border points of each class and skip the ones in the middle of same class borders

Comment: Thank you for that, @juvian. That makes more sense to me now. Can you please post that as the answer, so I can accept it and mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are picking 2 instances that are very close to each other but have different class. That means it is highly possible that the new point is in a border that separates the classes, which means it is important to keep it in the set we will use later for classification. That´s why you add it to Z.

If they were the same class, that means the new point gives no useful information than what we already have in Z, so we skip it and don´t add it. The intuition is that we try to only keep the border points of each class and skip the ones in the middle of same class borders.

Keep in mind that it is still a greedy approach, maybe a point we discard would have been useful if we had processed in another order. Also useful is the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#CNN_for_data_reduction).